# A question on fixed point iteration scheme

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Consider the function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
2^{- \bigg\{ 1+ \bigg( \log_2 \big( \frac{1}{x}\big) \bigg)^{\frac{1}{\beta}} \bigg\}^{\beta} }& \text{for }x \in (0,1] \\
0 & \text{for }x=0, \\
\end{cases}
$$
where $\beta \in (0, \infty)$ is a parameter.

Consider the iterations
$$x_{k+1}=f(x_k),  k=0,1, \dots; x_0>0.$$

Which of the following statements are true about the iteration ?

1. For $\beta=1,$ the sequence {$x_k$} converges to $0$ linearly with asymptotic rate of convergence $\log _{10}2$
2. For $\beta>1,$ the sequence {$x_k$} does not converges to $0$
3. For $\beta \in (0,1),$ the sequence {$x_k$} converges to $0$ sub-linearly
4. For $\beta \in (0,1),$ the sequence {$x_k$} converges to $0$ super-linearly

**My attempt:**

1. By putting $\beta=1,$ we get $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ for all $x \in [0,1].$ I am able to see that for this value of $\beta,$ the sequence $x_k$ converges to $0.$ But as for the convergence rate, I think it is with the convergence rate $\frac{1}{2}.$ So, option 1 is FALSE. But the key says that 1 is a correct option. If so, then, how to see that the convergence rate is $\log _{10}2$ ?
2. By putting $\beta=2$ and $x_0=1,$ I am able to see that the sequence $x_k$ is converging to $0.$ So, option 2 is FALSE, which is correct according to the key.

As for 3) and 4), I am confused on how to approach the problem.
The key says 1 and 3 are correct options.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

When the problem says "converges to $0$ linearly" this means that the number of decimal digits of precision increases at a linear rate.  For example, the sequence
$$\{0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 0.9999, \ldots \}$$
converges to $1$ at a linear rate of about $1$ digit per sequence term.  In your case,
$$\{0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, \ldots \}$$
is also linear convergence, this time to $0$, and at a rate of $\log_{10} 2$ digits per iteration.

To study the behavior of the forward orbits of $f$, consider the auxiliary function
$$g(x) = -\log_2 f(x) = (1 + (-\log_2 x)^{1/\beta})^\beta.$$
This suggests letting $y_n = -\log_2 x_n$, hence
$$y_{n+1} = -\log_2 x_{n+1} = -\log_2 f(x_n) = g(x_n) = (1 + (-\log_2 x_n)^{1/\beta})^\beta = (1 + y_n^{1/\beta})^\beta.$$  And this in turn implies
$$y_{n+1}^{1/\beta} = 1 + y_n^{1/\beta},$$ which suggests the same trick again, this time defining $$z_n = y_n^{1/\beta} = (-\log_2 x_n)^{1/\beta},$$ hence
$$z_{n+1} = 1 + z_n.$$
This allows us to unfold the recurrence and obtain
$$(-\log_2 x_n)^{1/\beta} = z_n = n + z_0 = n + (-\log_2 x_0)^{1/\beta}.$$
Now solving for $x_n$ yields
$$\boxed{x_n = 2^{-(n + (-\log_2 x_0)^{1/\beta})^\beta}}.$$
For $x_0 \in (0,1]$, we note $-\log_2 x_0 \in [1, \infty)$, hence $$z_0 = (-\log_2 x_0)^{1/\beta} \in [1, \infty).$$  We have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{-(n + z_0)^\beta},$$
and since $\beta > 0$, $(n+z_0)^\beta \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  Hence $x_n \to 0$ for all initial choices of $x_0$ and $\beta$.

I leave the question of the rate of convergence is left as an exercise.  How would you determine this based on the information provided above?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question. I am able to understand your solution but not able to use that knowledge to arrive at the convergence rates. In that direction, I have a natural doubt to ask. 1) How did you take $y_n$ and $z_n$ as you have defined in the sense that what were your thoughts before and after you took that choice ? This is because I feel that a novel way is used to do some analysis, which is not naturally coming to me.  2) The convergence rate is a function of $\beta$ and $x_0.$ How to use that idea to arrive at the exact convergence rate given $\beta$ and $x_0.$

Comment: The usual definition of rate of convergence does not (directly) involve the number of correct digits. We normally say that $x_n$ converges to zero with rate $p$ simply if $\lim \frac{|x_{n+1}|}{|x_n|^p} = K_{\infty} (\ne 0, \infty)$.